# Probability density function estimation for rare events

Tags: probability-distributions

My goal is to numerically estimate the ***probability density function (pdf)*** $P(f)$ for the function $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$. Here the random variables $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ are drawn from the independent identically distributed Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Formally, $P(f)$ can be written as
$$
P(f)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x_1\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x_n\ \delta\left(f-f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\right)e^{-\frac{x^2_1+\cdots+x^2_n}{2}},
$$
where $\delta(x)$ denotes the Dirac-Delta function.

Numerically, I can sample random variables $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n}$ according to Gaussian distribution $N$ ($N\gg1$) times, and collect the $N$ values of $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ to obtain the pdf $P(f)$.

However, when the probability to draw a state $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ with $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is very small, i.e., within the regimes where $P(f)\ll1$, the numerical method I mentioned above becomes very inefficient since there're very few events in the regimes $P(f)\ll1$, among the total $N$ events. This means I need very large $N$ to correctly estimate $P(f)$ for $P(f)\ll1$.

**My question is: It that a way (ways) to efficiently estimate the pdf for $P(f)\ll1$?** I note that the wiki for [Metropolis–Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) states that the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm can be used to sample rare states more likely (see the *Use in numerical integration* section). I'm not familiar with the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm, especially for the estimation of pdf. Any references will be helpful.

Comment: A keyword to look out for is "importance sampling"